# Are "Class 2" prescription TENS units any better than OTC TENS units?

Tags: pain, back, musculoskeletal-system, prescription, muscle

I have been prescribed a TENS unit for pain.  TENS stands for ***T***ranscutaneous **E**lectrical **N**erve **S**timulation.

The medical equipment company is planning on selling me a Compass Health (aka Roscoe Medical) TENS DT-3002 unit.  The details of the unit can be seen here: http://www.roscoemedical.com/item/DT3002/TENS-3000-Analog/

The description of that unit calls it a "Class 2" unit and states that a prescription is required (which I have).

For about the same amount of money, I can buy any number of OTC TENS units that look a lot nicer and have great reviews (although some of the reviews could be "paid" reviews).

For example, the #1 selling unit on Amazon is currently [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00NCRE4GO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NCRE4GO) and the #2 selling unit is currently [http://www.amazon.com/Lifetime-HealthmateForever-Electrotherapy-Electronic-Management/dp/B00O7CM12W/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O7CM12W) *(I have no affiliation with Amazon, the sellers, or the manufacturers, nor have I used any affiliate codes in the links.)*

Are there therapeutic advantages to the "Class 2" TENS units that require a prescription, when compared to OTC units like the example provided (or other OTC products)?

Are there therapeutic advantages to the OTC products over the prescription "Class 2" products?

Why are some OTC while others are prescription-only "Class 2" products?